# how can I distribute xmlrpc-c library with my project?

Tags: c, plugins, xmlrpcclient

in my C project I've referenced xmlrpc-c library from sourceforge.net in order to use xmlrpc-client.

my question is how can I distribute this library so other users don't need to download/install package from internet.

If its possible that I can distribute it with my .so file - it will be best.

Answer (score 0):

http://xmlrpc-c.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/xmlrpc-c/trunk/doc/COPYING?view=markup
states:

> ```
> Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
>   modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
>   are met:
>  1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
> notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
> 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
> notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
> documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
> 3. The name of the author may not be used to endorse or promote products
> derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
> ```

Comment: my prob. is how to, not related to licensing or author or permissions, I mean how can I make installer type of thing, I'm making pidgin plugin, without xmlrpc-client, I can direct distribute my plugin.so files to other users.

Answer (score 0):

On what platform? On Linux, it is considered best practice not to ship the library and instead rely on the packaging system of the OS: just list the library as a dependency of your package. Usually that's the packager's job, not the developer's job, unless you are both developer and packager. Other OSes may have different accepted practices.

Comment: yes I need for ubuntu only, and I'm the developer and packager :), but I don't know how to package the plugin, I'm making my plugin with option `make my_plugin.so`

Comment: Packaging is a vast topic... and that's why it is usually not done by the same people who develop the code. You may want to read the [Ubuntu packaging guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Complete) (it's not short!).